Modelling with parametric volume of revolution,
Modelling question
I think the  curve is only the part of the cross-section from Q to R. I understand how to do the integration for part b of the question but can't figure out how I would find a and b. I know the max y value is 2cm and the min y value is 0. Also, that x is 3 when y is zero. I am not sure how I find the corresponding values of theta

I think they mean that the endpoints of the curve are also the endpoints of the given $\theta$ range (or how else could it be meant?)

so would  acos^2(pie/6) = 3 as the x value of R is 3?

I don't see why you think the $x$ value would be 3, I see no 3 mentioned in the link. But you know more about the details perhaps, so I leave that to you. Anyhow it is not called  acos^2(pie/6),  but $a\cos(\pi/6)$, spelled $a\cos(\pi/6)$ when entered in StackExchange text.

Where is the origin, the intersection of x and y axis ?
